# Bash script in-braces weird escaping and pound symbol

Tags: linux, bash

I'm reading a bash script function which takes an input variable with escape codes as first parameter and cycles on its characters, anyway I can't understand these lines:

```
local input="${1//\"/\\\"}" output="" i char within_code=0
    for ((i=0; i < ${#input}; ++i)); do
        char="${input:i:1}"                     # get current character
```

I guess my bash-foo isn't strong enough.

- What is `"${1//\"/\\\"}"` ? The first parameter should be `$1` I think.
- What does the `#` in `${#input}` do?

The rest I can, more or less, understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansions are explained in the [bash manual Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

1. It substitutes all occurrences of `"` with `\"` in `$1`. Yes, `$1` expands to the first positional parameter.
2. The `${#input}` expands to the length of `$input`.